# How to echo this Value

Tags: php, echo

I have this value from an XML file

```
<InfoExtractor:views>35490904</InfoExtractor:views>
```

From - http://www.infoextractor.org/upfiles/songlinks.txt.xml

it is not showing when I use this code

```
foreach ($viewfile->channel->item as $viewfileinfo):
        $title=$viewfileinfo->title;
        $views=$viewfileinfo->InfoExtractor:views;

echo "<span> ",$title,"</span> <br/> <span> ",$views,"</span> <br/>";
```

The title is showing fine when I echo, but how do I output the views value to echo?

==========

I found the answer, I changed the line to

```
$views=$viewfileinfo->children('InfoExtractor', true)->views;
```

This takes the colon into account.

Comment: not sure how the data is parsed in the iterator. You can print_r($viewfileinfo) to see how the data is coming through and then try to display that way.

Comment: `print_r` or `var_dump` maybe?

Comment: Show the full XML document.

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_object_vars to capture an array, then view all the keys and values to determine precisely what you want to echo:

```
$views_array = get_object_vars($views);

foreach ($views_array as $key => $value) {
    echo 'key = '.$key.', value = '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```